# PHP+.htaccess: How to create URL like with ID+name of an article?

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I am thinking how to create the routing system like this:

```
http://website.com/something/12345-my-new-car
```

which says that in URL is placed the ID and slug name of an article.
My current setup is the following (http://website.com/something/12345):

```
RewriteRule ^something/(.*)$  index\.php?id=something&something_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I would like to add the slug name behind the article ID.
First idea - manually build it - something like:

```
<a href="/something/<?php echo $id.'-'.$slug;?>">link</a>
```

And then to get the current URL and with `explode()` parse the url (`/`) and then again `explode()` for parsing `-` in the `12345-my-new-car` => which return me `12345`. And now I would just pick out the respective article.

But I don't really like this way, it's a bit clumsy.

Is there any better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: I asked @user984621, no you faa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my my `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9_/]+)/?$ index.php?args=$1 [L]
```

In my code I use this method :

```
$agri = explode("/",$_GET['args']);
```

And I have table with my argumants. Now I can make with this all.

Comment: Hi man, thank you for your answer. But this conditions solves this kind of URLs: `website.com/blabla/12345/article-name`, or not? Also, is for SEO better `/12345/article-name` or `/12345-article-name`? Or doesn't matter?

Comment: For SEO this isn't important. In my solution you can write website.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/... and will be good. You don't must write website.com/1222-article-name. You can easy write : website.com/1999/art-name

Comment: @user984621 couldn't you then use `$items = explode('-', $argi[1]);`