# GET parameter is fetching undesired file extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

GET is fetching the file extension along with the value.
Here is my .htaccess -

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/(.*)/$ /Test3.php?u=$1&i=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/(.*)$ /Test3.php?u=$1&i=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/$ /Test3.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

File Test3.php is like this -

```
<?php
echo $_GET['u'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_GET['i'];
?>
```

Url I'm passing - http://example.com/test/something/more/

The output on my browser -

```
something/more.php
```

Where as the desired output is

```
something
more
```

I have scraped whole of my website to fix this but no luck. Not sure why am I getting that php at the end and the complete value after http://example.com/test/ is going to the first parameter only.

Please help !

Thanks All ! I believe the issue to be coming from this line. Pleas suggest a solution with regard to this.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I don't know if the regex is greedy, but it might be the issue, because (.*) could mean "everything including the slash".

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php` in your new code looks like it adds .php because of `\.php`

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert in RewruteRules, but I know some regular expressions and the `.*` in:

```
^test/(.*)/(.*)/$
```

means it matches anything including /'s.

You might want try:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /Test3.php?u=$1&i=$2 [L,NC]
//removed this one because they are basically the same
//by adding '/?' it says that the slash is optional
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/?$ /Test3.php?u=$1 [L,NC]
```

Someone might want to make a suggestion to the regex, but I think it will work for your purpose.

**EDIT**: Or you can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663292/1700963

If anyone has any better example please edit or make a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I found a page describing the greedy thing I was refering to in my comment :
http://www.mspo.com/how-to/greed-in-apache-rewrite-rules.html